# How to map JSON to Java Object

Tags: java, json

In my web-service, I'm sending a json inside the post request to server. In server I need to put this information into Argument of my called function.

This is my function on the server side :

```
   @Path("/myapp/myfunction/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class SiderRecommender {


        @POST
        @Path("recs")
        public Response getRecommendations(User usr)  {

               // Here I want to access request payload inside 
               //usr  object. For example : 
              // System.out.println("limit sending by client:"+usr.getLimit());
              // System.out.println("size of List sent by client:"+usr.getNames().size());
       }
}
```

Here is my User class :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {
    private List<String> names;
    private int limit;

    public List<String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public void setNames(List<String> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public int getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }

    public void setLimit(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
}
```

And lastly, this is how I send request on client :

```
  var url = 'http://localhost:8080/myapp/myfunction/recs';
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  xhr.onload = function() {
  var text = xhr.responseText;
  var title = getTitle(text);
  alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
};

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
  };
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"names":[{"names":"SampleName1"},    {"names":"SampleName2"},{"names":"SampleName3"}],"limit":100 }));
```

I think that, I might made a mistake with the syntax inside JSON.stringify(). Does it looks like right ?

**EDIT** I'm using JACKSON by the way.

**EDIT2**

In browser, I'm getting this error:

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@6508327b; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.mypackage.User["names"])
```

Comment: What's the exact problem you're facing right now? Is something failing somewhere?

Comment: are you getting exception?

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between what you say is your User class, and the actual name of the class that you posted: IdsRequest. Was that a typo?

Comment: @AlinPandichi for the sake of simplicity, I had changed the class names but I forgot to changed it. Now I've corrected, could you look at again?

Comment: @NiteshVirani I've updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with JSON object that you are passing from JavaScript.

```
{
    "names": [
        {
            "names": "SampleName1"
        },
        {
            "names": "SampleName2"
        },
        {
            "names": "SampleName3"
        }
    ],
    "limit": 100
}
```

you have "names" under "names" that will map to `List<Map<String,String>>` in Java object.

Either change your Java Object or change the JSON object as shown below to map it to `List<String>`

```
{
    "names": [
        "SampleName1",
        "SampleName2",
        "SampleName3"
    ],
    "limit": 100
}
```

---

Must read [JacksonInFiveMinutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

Below images are taken from http://json.org/

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes exactly, I was suspecting from it too, but I could not find any documentation about it probably because I do not know the correct keywords for searching.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify should work for your use-case. You haven't mentioned what's the exact problem you're facing, but your json seems to be incorrect (as compared to the object you're trying to map it to).

Your domain object is named as IdsRequest, your service consumes User and your json has names having an array of names and the limit. In your json, the root element is "names", which has an array of names, this isn't how your domain object User looks like. So, you get the error while mapping the two.